# Animate Custom buttons iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button

I have created some custom buttons and they don't animate like system buttons. I want them to animate like default system buttons. And the problem is when I change the button type from custom to system they loose the original image color to default blue color, and if I make them custom they maintain their original image color but stop animating. Screen shot is attached please have a look [sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5JFH.png)
Blue one has type system so it animates but loose its original color and green one is of custom type but it dont animate like system the blue one.

I want my button images in green color and animate like system button. Any clue how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not creating simple system button, but set it green tint color also to get this green effect you need set image render type(in the assets) "Render as Template image". I will add images below sou you can easily understand what I'm talking about.[image]

This option is setting in attributes inspector in assets catalog for chosen image. 
[image]
This options you can find in .storyboard file in "Attributes inspector" window for selected button. 
Or by setting from code

```
button.setTintColor(UIColor.greenColor());
```